# Problem installing packages in multi-stage Dockerfile in the final stage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create a minimal docker image.
For that purpose I am using the following multi-stage build dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as base

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

FROM base as builder

ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.1.13

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm \
    libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev \
    libffi-dev liblzma-dev python3.9-venv --yes && \
    pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION" && \
    python -m venv /venv && \
    poetry export -f requirements.txt | /venv/bin/pip install -r /dev/stdin

COPY . /app
RUN poetry build && /venv/bin/pip install dist/*.whl

FROM base as final

ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

COPY --from=builder /venv /venv

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps curl

# for prometheus
EXPOSE 9090

CMD ["my_command"]
```

However, no matter where I put the final install command in the final stage the commands are not found in the final image.

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps curl`

I have tried putting it before and after the COPY and ENV and  still nothing...

Finally, I added another stage between base and builder just to run this command and then everything works fine.

It's bugging me why this would be the case though. Any ideas what's wrong with the dockerfile above?

Comment: Can you try `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl` command and check if curl is getting installed ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Hi joan3000 and everyone else,
you need to check the **ENTRYPOINT** of the *"python:3.9-slim"*-image. Docker will combine the **ENTRYPOINT** and the **CMD** of the Docker Image. If the **ENTRYPOINT** is not correctly set to pass the environment variables to your defined **CMD** command, then you wont be able to use the changes made in the *"PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH"* variable in the final image. To ensure that the environment variables are properly passed, you can specify the **ENTRYPOINT** explicitly in your final stage and set it to *["bash", "-c"]*. This will allow you to execute commands in a shell and properly interpret environment variables. With this change, the environment variables should be available, and the *"PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH"*-modification *(and other env vars)* will take effect on your **CMD** command in your final image.

My approach to the solution refers to one **possible problem**, the *real problem* may not be addressed, which is because i can't build the image myself and therefore can't help any further.
For building and testing i would need **your files referenced in the image**, or even better a git repo.

*I wish everyone a good day!*

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question.